# Split train data to train and validation by using tensorflow_datasets.load (TF 2.1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to run the following Colab project, but when I want to split the training data into validation and train parts I get this error:

```
KeyError: "Invalid split train[:70%]. Available splits are: ['train']"
```

I use the following code:

```
(training_set, validation_set), dataset_info = tfds.load(
'tf_flowers',
split=['train[:70%]', 'train[70%:]'],
with_info=True,
as_supervised=True,
)
```

How I can fix this error?

Comment: what Colab project?

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/courses/udacity_intro_to_tensorflow_for_deep_learning/l06c02_exercise_flowers_with_transfer_learning.ipynb

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [Tensorflow Dataset docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/splits#specifying_a_percentage_slice) the approach you presented is now supported. Splitting is possible by passing split parameter to `tfds.load` like so `split="test[:70%]"`.

```py
(training_set, validation_set), dataset_info = tfds.load(
    'tf_flowers',
    split=['train[:70%]', 'train[70%:]'],
    with_info=True,
    as_supervised=True,
)
```

With the above code the `training_set` has 2569 entries, while `validation_set` has 1101.

Thank you [Saman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2959717/saman) for the comment on API deprecation:
In previous Tensorflow version it was possible to use `tfds.Split` API which is now deprecated:

```py
(training_set, validation_set), dataset_info = tfds.load(
    'tf_flowers',
    split=[
        tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit(tfds.percent[:70]),
        tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit(tfds.percent[70:])
    ],
    with_info=True,
    as_supervised=True,
)
```

Comment: Error: Split' object has no attribute 'subsplit'

Comment: This worked for me, maybe you can update your answer: 

(tfds_train_ds, tfds_test_ds), tfds_info = tfds.load(
    dataset_name, split=[ 'train[:50%]', 'train[50%:]'], with_info=True)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to allocate `training`, `validation`, and `test` subsets (70%, 15%, 15%), this is the code (got it from [here](https://stackabuse.com/split-train-test-and-validation-sets-with-tensorflow-datasets-tfds/))

```
(training_set, validation_set, test_set), dataset_info = tfds.load(
    'tf_flowers',
    split=['train[:70%]', 'train[70%:85%]', 'train[85%:]',
    with_info=True,
    as_supervised=True,
    )
```