# Spliting datasets with tfds

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to split `tf_flower`dataset using `tfds.Split`

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

splits = tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit(weighted=[80,10,10])
(raw_train, raw_val, raw_test), metadata = tfds.load('tf_flowers',
                                                     split=list(splits),
                                                     data_dir="./dataset",
                                                     as_supervised=True,
                                                     with_info=True)
```

but i always get this error.

```
AttributeError: 'Split' object has no attribute 'subsplit'
```

what is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Please provide the fully reproducible code for this error.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to run your code in TF 2, I didn't get the error you specified, but a different one,

```
AssertionError: Unrecognized instruction format: NamedSplit('train')(tfds.percent[0:80])
```

However, I was able to get the following to work.

```
(raw_train, raw_val, raw_test), metadata = tfds.load('tf_flowers',
                                                     split=["train[:80%]","train[80%:90%]","train[90%:]"],
                                                     data_dir="./dataset",
                                                     as_supervised=True,
                                                     with_info=True)
```

Comment: I tried this way too it is working. this post is using the similar way of mine but still doesnt work and giving same error to me https://stackoverflow.com/q/59905761/13740931